# Spring Boot MVC returning JSON and XML fails to return the latter

Tags: json, xml, spring, spring-boot

I am toying around with a small project that contains a couple of REST endpoints one returning a response of type `JSON` and the other `XML`. I am using the basic out of the box setup and OpenAPI generator to generate the stubs. For reference this is the task that creates the server stubs:

```
tasks.register('openApiGenerateServer', GenerateTask) {
    group                   = 'openapi tools'
    description             = 'Generate server side spring stubs for the Test API'
    generatorName           = 'spring'
    inputSpec               = "$projectDir/src/main/resources/openapi/springtest.yaml" as String
    outputDir               = layout.buildDirectory.dir("generated/server").map { it.asFile.toPath().toString() }
    invokerPackage          = 'com.studiosus.sis.springtest'
    apiPackage              = 'com.studiosus.sis.springtest.api'
    modelPackage            = 'com.studiosus.sis.springtest.model'
    enablePostProcessFile   = true
    skipOverwrite           = false
    modelFilesConstrainedTo = []
    configOptions           = [
            dateLibrary         : 'java8',
            serializationLibrary: 'jackson',
            library             : 'spring-boot',
            useBeanValidation   : 'true',
            interfaceOnly       : 'true',
            serializableModel   : 'true',
            useTags             : 'true',
            sourceFolder        : 'src/main/java',
            testFolder          : 'src/test/java',
            useSpringBoot3      : 'true',
            openApiNullable     : 'true',
            withXml             : 'true'
    ]
}
```

While I see that both APIs have the correct media types, when I attempt to invoke the one returning XML I get the following warnings and an error:

```
2024-01-23T01:58:33.474+02:00  WARN 5501 --- [               ] x.MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter : Failed to evaluate Jackson serialization for type [class com.studiosus.sis.springtest.model.TestResponseXml]: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Conflicting/ambiguous property name definitions (implicit name 'id'): found multiple explicit names: [{}id, id], but also implicit accessor: [method com.studiosus.sis.springtest.model.TestResponseXml#setId(java.lang.Integer)][visible=true,ignore=false,explicitName=false]
2024-01-23T01:58:33.476+02:00  WARN 5501 --- [               ] x.MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter : Failed to evaluate Jackson serialization for type [class com.studiosus.sis.springtest.model.TestResponseXml]: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Conflicting/ambiguous property name definitions (implicit name 'id'): found multiple explicit names: [{}id, id], but also implicit accessor: [method com.studiosus.sis.springtest.model.TestResponseXml#setId(java.lang.Integer)][visible=true,ignore=false,explicitName=false]
2024-01-23T01:58:33.483+02:00  WARN 5501 --- [               ] x.MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter : Failed to evaluate Jackson serialization for type [class com.studiosus.sis.springtest.model.ErrorResponse]: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Conflicting/ambiguous property name definitions (implicit name 'code'): found multiple explicit names: [{}code, code], but also implicit accessor: [method com.studiosus.sis.springtest.model.ErrorResponse#setCode(java.lang.Integer)][visible=true,ignore=false,explicitName=false]
2024-01-23T01:58:33.485+02:00  WARN 5501 --- [               ] x.MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter : Failed to evaluate Jackson serialization for type [class com.studiosus.sis.springtest.model.ErrorResponse]: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Conflicting/ambiguous property name definitions (implicit name 'code'): found multiple explicit names: [{}code, code], but also implicit accessor: [method com.studiosus.sis.springtest.model.ErrorResponse#setCode(java.lang.Integer)][visible=true,ignore=false,explicitName=false]
2024-01-23T01:58:33.487+02:00  WARN 5501 --- [               ] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Failure in @ExceptionHandler com.ariskourt.springtest.exception.ApplicationExceptionHandler#handleException(Exception)

org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: No acceptable representation
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:256) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:245) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:78) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.doResolveHandlerMethodException(ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java:432) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.doResolveException(AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.java:74) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:175) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.resolveException(HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.java:80) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(DispatcherServlet.java:1357) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1160) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1106) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:340) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPerTaskExecutor$TaskRunner.run(ThreadPerTaskExecutor.java:314) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.VirtualThread.run(VirtualThread.java:309) ~[na:na]

2024-01-23T01:58:33.492+02:00  WARN 5501 --- [               ] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter for [class com.studiosus.sis.springtest.model.TestResponseXml] with preset Content-Type 'null']
```

I have tried debugging this and I cannot figure out what I am missing. I have tried adding explicit mapping configurations for Spring (in order to handle JSON and XML payloads), I have tried setting the default media type to JSON and I have also tried creating separate `ObjectMapper` and `XmlMapper` instances both added the individual converters. None of those worked and frankly I am a bit lost. I have a similar example that uses `WebFlux` and in this case everything works fine so I am not really sure what I am missing. Can anyone shed some light?

For reference I am using Spring Boot 3.2.2, Java 21 (with Virtual Threads enabled) and the basic Spring boot configuration.